# Looping inside an array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with my code here. It's a jquery-bracket project.

I have an object that has an array inside, there's a line of array i want to loop so I don't have to manually generated those lines

```js
var team = ["Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4"];
var result = [1, 2, 2, 1];
var teams = "";
for (i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
  teams += [`["${team[i++]}"`, ` "${team[i]}"], \n`]
}
var singleElimination = {
  "teams": [
    // line that I needed for loop
    [team[0], team[1]],
    [team[2], team[3]],
  ],
  "results": [
    [
      [
        // also line that I needed for loop
        [result[0], result[1]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have tried to pass the loop into a variable and passing them inside of an array, but it doesn't seems work.
sorry for my bad English, looking forward for the answer!

demo : https://quizzical-stonebraker-2d808a.netlify.com/

Comment: Could you please show an example of the result you want?

Comment: see the result here https://quizzical-stonebraker-2d808a.netlify.com/

Comment: It's much preferred if you can add all relevant information and code into your question.

Comment: not a graph, but the result you want as a js object

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use team.join(',');

eg:-

```
    var singleElimination = {
        "teams": [
        [team.join(',')]
```

Comment: doesn't work, it says `Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var team = ["Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4"];
var result = [1, 2, 2, 1];
var obj = {}
for(var i=0; i<team.length; i++){
 obj[team[i]] = result[i];
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: not the result I wanted, i need to loop the `[team[i], team[j]]`

Comment: Post the sample result JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var team = ["Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4"];
var result = [1, 2, 2, 1];
var singleElimination = {
  teams: [
    // line that I needed for loop
    [team[0], team[1]],
    [team[2], team[3]]
  ],
  results: [
    [
      [
        // also line that I needed for loop
        [result[0], result[1]],
        [result[2], result[3]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
};
console.log("singleElimination", singleElimination);
var _teams = "";
singleElimination.teams.forEach(element => {
  element.forEach((team, index) => {
    _teams += element[index] + ", ";
  });
});
var _teamResults = "";
singleElimination.results.forEach(element => {
  element.forEach((team, index) => {
    _teamResults += element[index] + ", ";
  });
});
console.log("_teams", _teams);
console.log("_teamResults", _teamResults);
```